# Gradle use RES dir from outside location

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How can I set in my gradle file to use the whole RES dir from a specific location? I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and gradle 0.4.0 experimental.

Is there any official documentation about gradle experimental plugins? I have found this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Multiple-NDK-Projects

Is there any documentation that is more complete and contains more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use somenthing like that:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        manifest.source {
            srcDir 'folder'
            include 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        resources.source.srcDir 'folder/res'
        java.source.srcDir 'folder/src'
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I have build flavors, I can specific for that flavor eg: android.sources {
    main {
        ...
    } googleFree{resources.source.srcDir 'folder/res' }
} Since I only need the resources dir from an outside location ?

Comment: I am not sure about it (never used) but it should work.